# Woocommerce optimize images for mobile

Tags: image, optimization, mobile, woocommerce, pagespeed

I'm trying to improve pagespeed results for my clients.
I'm making an eshop with woocommerce and although I get 90-92% for desktop in the mobile I only have 38-40% because of images that it says to optimize them.

I've already make several changes for that reason, using EWWW Image optimizer plugin, which is very good and lets you customize several things for the images. I've deactivated all the rest of the images that theme or wordpress creates and I don't need.
I only use `shop_thumbnail`, `shop_catalog`, `shop_single` resize formats but although that in desktop works good, in mobile gives me the above issue...

What can I do to make it work also in mobile properly? Is there any code that I can input for ex srcset (I've noticed that this places a role for it)?